# Why does giving my array values with increments of 2 also affect indices in a later for each loop?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, foreach

When i want to add values to my array with a for loop, whatever multiplier the values hold, will also multiply the indices later in the for each loop to print them.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArr = new int[10];
        
        for(int index = 0; index < intArr.length; index++) {
            intArr[index] = index;
        }
        for(int index : intArr) {
            System.out.println(intArr[index]);
        }
    }
}

out:

0
1
2
.
.
9
```

Here it's working as intended since 1 * 1 = 1. But if i want to add values to my array with increments of 2 for example it will print out the indices with increments of two also.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] intArr = new int[10];
        
        for(int index = 0; index < intArr.length; index++) {
            intArr[index] = index * 2;
        }
        for(int index : intArr) {
            System.out.println(intArr[index]);
        }
    }
}

out:
0 (0 * 2 = 0)
4 (2 * 2)
8 (4)
12(6)
16(8)
```

And then i get an index out of bounds exception since there isn't a 10th index. Same will happen with 3 (0,9,27) and higher also. If i write it with a regular for loop instead of a for each, all works well. Why?

I would expect the index numbers to be independent from the values they hold.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In detail, how does the 'for each' loop work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/in-detail-how-does-the-for-each-loop-work-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

The `for-each` loop iterates the **values** in the array, not the indices.

```
for(int index : intArr) {
    System.out.println(intArr[index]);
}
```

should be

```
for(int value : intArr) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```